# can the jmeter master also be a load generator

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

Setup:

Jmeter Master:

- machine1

Jmeter slaves:

- machine1
- machine2

Sometimes, I get a

> java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host

when the Jmeter Master (machine1) tries to connect to the slave (machine1)

Configuring remote engine for XX.XX.XX.XX
[info] Failure connecting to remote host: XX.XX.XX.XX java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: XX.XX.XX.XX; nested exception is: 
[info]  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Any idea? Is it even ok for the Jmeter master and slave to be on the same machine?

I'm using the Jmeter maven plugin.  I manually start the jmeter-server process before each test.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter distributed setup should be on 2 separate machines, otherwise it does not solve the purpose.

Ideal setup is:
Master (machine 1)

Slave 1 (machine 2)
Slave 2 (machine 3)